# directory isn't recognized as being a directory

Tags: bash

I would like to make a bash function that lists all the directories (and files) inside a given directory.

```
searchInRepo(){
    file_list=`ls $1`
    #echo $file_list

    for aFile in $file_list; do
        echo "$aFile --"
        # case : directory
        if [ -d $aFile ]
        then
            echo "$aFile ***"
            cd $aFile
            searchInRepo $aFile
            cd ..
        # case : file
        elif [ -f $aFile ]
        then
            echo "$aFile is a regular file"
        fi
    done 
}
```

As you see, this is a recursive function. When I call it with `ls $1` (listing parameter's files) it doesn't recognize the directories as being directories. When I just use `ls`(no argument involved) everything works fine.

Any suggestions here ?
Cheers !

Comment: what are the permissions of the file/directory?

Comment: It's not a good practice to use `for` loop to iterate through files. It results in unexpected behaviour.. Instead use `while`-`read` combination.

Comment: user has read and write permissions. Other and group just have read permissions. As it works fine with just ls, I guess permissions are fine ?

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use `ls` when bash can do it for you? This will check to make sure the argument has a trailing `/*` so it will work with bare directory names.

```
if [[ ! "$1" =~ /\*$ ]]
then
    if [[ ! "$1" =~ /$ ]]
    then
        searchpath="$1/*"
    else
        searchpath="$1*"
    fi
fi
echo "Searching $searchpath"

for f in $searchpath; do
    if [ -d "$f" ]
    then
        echo "Directory -> $f"
    else
        echo "File -> $f"
    fi
done
```

Comment: When I call my function, I use './directory' as argument (because my .sh file is inside that same directory). After `echo "Directory -> $f"` I call that same function with $f as parameter, but it doesn't seem to work : f is always ./directory

Comment: Ah, in that case you would need to append `/*` to the argument before passing it to the `for` loop.

Comment: Could you edit your code to see how it would look like, because I'm not sure I understand

Comment: There are doubtless more elegant ways to do it, but I've done a quick and dirty check to make sure there's a trailing /*

Comment: Even though prints are a bit messy (long directory paths), this works perfectly ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: If you just need the name, try `basename /very/long/path/to/this.file`

Comment: It doesn't seem to change anything (except the fact that my script thinks basename is one of my arguments)

Comment: `echo $(basename $aFile) is a regular file`

Comment: Works perfectly ! Only the file names are displayed !

Answer (score 0):

Why even use for loop, `find` is made for this.

```
find . # List all files and directories recursively
find . -type f  # List only files
find . -maxdepth 1 # List all files and directories in current directory
```

If you are using git, you can also use `git ls-files`

Comment: Thanks ! But for learning purposes I would like to replicate the usage of find by recreating a similar function

Comment: Then try to define your function to take directory path as input instead of changing directories and bash doesn't work very well if there are spaces in filenames. set IFS=$'\n\t'

Comment: Actually, I take 2 paths when calling the executable. How could I use IFS to act on those paths ?

Comment: Thanks ! It works with spaces, but I'm still unable to enter the directory. With @miken32's code it'll still list those directories as being regular files

Comment: Show me your inputs and outputs, execute `find .` and your command output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96384/discussion-between-tanguyh-and-rozuur).